# Invalid mode ('a+') or filename - Pandas large file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am working with pandas. Since i am merging large dataframes in pandas, its going out of memory error. To try to solve this i am splitting one of the two dataframes and merging it with the other. and storing the result of that merge to a csv file. When the CSV File reaches 4.01 GB, i get the error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('a+') or filename: 'D:\\New folder\\abc.csv'
```

Can anyone tell me the reason why this is occuring, and any workarounds through this?
I am using NTFS file system.

**Code:**

```
for chunk in dfsrc_table1:
    pop=pop+1
    print pop
    dftarget = pd.merge( chunk, dfsrc_table2, left_on=objRule.getColumnLeft(), right_on=objRule.getColumnRight(),suffixes=('', '_y') )
    with open("D:\New folder\\abc.csv",'a+') as statFile:
        if(len(statFile.readlines())>0):
            dftarget.to_csv(statFile,index=False,header=False,encoding=c.UTF8,float_format='%0.2f')
        else:
            dftarget.to_csv(statFile,index=False,header=True,encoding=c.UTF8,float_format='%0.2f')
    dftarget = pd.concat(chunk for chunk in pd.read_csv("D:\New folder\\abc.csv",chunksize = 50000))
```

Comment: are you using 32bit python?

Comment: 64bit. 32 bit just python gives Out of memory error way earlier

Comment: did you try using `to_csv` with a `chunksize`?

Comment: which line is the error from?

Comment: dftarget.to_csv(statFile,index=False,header=True,encoding=c.UTF8,float_format='%0.2f')